# Upload local file to SharePoint Online using HttpWebRequest

Tags: rest, sharepoint, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to upload a file to a SharePoint online site that I have permissions for, I have tried using an HttpWebRequest to get an XDocument to allow me to upload a file but when I call an HttpWebResponse I get the error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

I'm unable to use SharePoint client object model as this app is to be used on PCs that don't have a SharePoint installation.

Comment: Are you sending the necessary credentials with your request? How about set the Impersonation level, and setting the authentication method to NTLM? Please share some code, or at least a stacktrace that might give a better idea of your problems

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the PCs have a SharePoint installation. What matters is if the server running the web application has the appropriate .NET library version.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a digest:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
string cmd = "_api/contextinfo";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentLength", "0");
StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("");
var response = client.PostAsync(cmd, httpContent).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    JsonObject val = JsonValue.Parse(content).GetObject();
    JsonObject d = val.GetNamedObject("d");
    JsonObject wi = d.GetNamedObject("GetContextWebInformation");
    retVal = wi.GetNamedString("FormDigestValue");
}
```

Then you can use the following example to upload the file and retrieve its metadata from the http response:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");
IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await path.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
Byte[] content = new byte[fileStream.Size];
reader.ReadBytes(content);
ByteArrayContent file = new ByteArrayContent(content);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(String.Concat("_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Project Photos')/RootFolder/Files/add(url='", filename, ".jpg',overwrite='true')?$expand=ListItemAllFields"), file);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var info = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JsonObject d = JsonValue.Parse(info.Result).GetObject();
    string id = d["d"].GetObject()["ListItemAllFields"].GetObject().GetNamedValue("ID").Stringify();
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to download the file contents, but it seems to be ignoring the `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true")` header and just giving me the XML metadata. Do you have a sample for downloading?

Comment: I'll get you one posted on my blog.  Give me a few.

Comment: I've posted my download solution (avoiding the HTTP Header) [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158085/9123)

Comment: I have a pretty extensive example of downloading a file in a standard C# application without using any of the SharePoint libraries [here](https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/sharepoint-rest-downloading-a-file-and-working-with-json-via-the-httpclient) now.